# What is the difference between this.parentElement and element.parentElement?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, parent-child

This code makes a button that deletes the table row, and it is worked, but I have some misconecpts,

Correct me if I am right in all this plz:-

```
 I know as following:-
```

1*- **(this)** in ***line4** it indicates for *main tag* which is **(tr)**.

2- The **element** in **line8** is the same thing as **(this)** in **line4**.

3- So, for that **(this)** in **line4**, and **(tr)** is the same thing as the element in **line8**

4- The *parentElement* indicates for the **(td)** .

And according to my understanding, I wrote this example down below:-

Example:  **tr**(this).**td**(parentElement)

Note:- This the [fiddle](https://repl.it/@hamzhsami/thisparentElement) code, in case you need it.

**javascript**

```
    var td4 = document.createElement('td'); 
              td4.setAttribute("id", "td4");
              td4.innerHTML = `<button 
             onclick=remove(this.parentElement)>X</button>` ***line4**
              tr.appendChild(td4);

    function remove(element){
             element.parentElement.remove(element) ***line8**
    }
```

---

---

**HTML**

```
<div class='table'>
    <table id="table">
        <th>
             <tr>
                <td>Task</td>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Urgency</td>
                <td>Done</td>
            </tr>
        </th>
        <button onclick=clearAll()> Clear All </button>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `index.html` is all JS code!

Comment: @AlwaysHelping

I update my question please read it again
and also update the index file in fiddle

Comment: There is no difference you can also do this and results will be the same => `element.parentElement.parentElement.remove(element)` and call the function this `remove(this)` - Same results.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping 

So everything I wrote is correct, right?

but why you wrote parentElement twice

Comment: The `this.parentElement` in `onclick=remove(this.parentElement)` refers to the parent element of the clicked element (`<td>`) and sends this `<td>` as a parameter value to the `remove()` function. The `remove()` function then gets the parent element of this send `<td>` which is the `<tr>` and removes this. So the `this` in line 4 is the `<button>` and element in line 8 is the `<td>`.

Comment: @HamzaSAMI I was about the add the explanation but @ mark baijens already added the same explanation. That’s exactly what is happening.

Comment: But what the *parentElement* indicate for in **line4** and **line8**

@MarkBaijens

Comment: @HamzaSAMI I told you that in my comment in line 4 its the parent element of the `<button>` so the `<td>` element. In line 8 it's the parent of the `<td>` so it's the `<tr>` element.

Comment: @MarkBaijens

The ***this.parentElement*** in onclick=remove(this.parentElement) refers to the parent element of the clicked element (<td>) 

---


You mean here that ***this.parentElement*** refers to (<tr>), correct?

Answer (score 0):

The `this.parentElement` in `onclick=remove(this.parentElement)` refers to the parent element of the clicked element () and sends this  as a parameter value to the remove() function. The remove() function then gets the parent element of this send  which is the `<tr>` and removes this. So the `this` in line 4 is the `<button>` and element in line 8 is the `<td>`.

You can see it in the snippet below when you press the button.

```js
//Create default tr for demonstration purpose
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
tr.innerHTML = "<td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td>";

var td4 = document.createElement('td');
td4.setAttribute("id", "td4");
//added console.log to show what this.parentElement is.
td4.innerHTML = `<button onclick=console.log("this.parentElement="+this.parentElement);remove(this.parentElement)>X</button>`;
tr.appendChild(td4);
document.querySelector("#table").appendChild(tr);

function remove(element) {
  //added console.log to show what element.parentElement is.
  console.log(`element.parentElement=${element.parentElement}`);
  element.parentElement.remove(element);
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <table id="table">
    <th>
      <tr>
        <td>Task</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Urgency</td>
        <td>Done</td>
      </tr>
    </th>
    <button onclick=clearAll()> Clear All </button>
  </table>
</div>
```